# How can I cause WHM to allocate resources to only one account?

Tags: dedicated-server

I have a Dedicated Server with cPanel/WHM management and I run one web-application in just one account,  so I need all server power (RAM and CPU time) to be directed to this account. I just don't know how WHM manages server resources between accounts.

Can it be done in my case?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install CloudLinux or BetterLinux they have the ability in shared hosting environments to prioritize resources.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what happens in WHM with one account? It have a quotes for one account or it uses whole server resources?

Comment: The system by default will use ALL resources unless limited by limits.conf and in /usr/local/apache/conf/php.conf. Keep in mind that all default security settings on the server come in to account.

Comment: I've got a heavy scripts that sometimes freezes on shared hosting, so I moved to dedicated with WHM. And you know, the scripts are still freezing. I am working on scripts optimizing but i really thought that moving to dedicated with more power would help. It is not. What would be your suggestion on that issue?

Comment: You need to find out what resources are being taxed. It could MySQL or an I/O issue.

Answer (score 1):

The server's resources will be allocated by the operating system as required.

I don't think you really want it to devote no RAM or CPU cycles to anything other than processes run by one account.  To do so would be very strange (and cause stability problems).

To allocate all resources available to hosting this one application of yours, just don't run anything else from the server.  If there aren't any other hosting accounts or services running, no resources will be dedicated to them, and I have no idea why you would put things on a server which you don't want to consume compute resources.

If your application is running slow and nothing else is competing with it for resources, chances are there is something wrong with the application itself, or elsewhere in your environment.  For instance, it might be buggy, or it might have a slow connection to its database if it has one (or to the internet).  Look at remote resources that are required.

Another thing that can happen in virtual hosting environments is that the VPS provider can underprovision disks such that access is slow.  Consider taking a look at `top`; if the majority of CPU time is going to `hi` (hardware interrupts, which disk access waiting falls under), that is the problem.  Also, check `iotop` to see if there is excessive disk I/O.

Comment: Thanks for advises. Well, at the start I used shared hosting and some day my DB became larger and it took a longer time for scripts to process DB. One day scripts crushed and my first idea was about weak shared hosting i use, so I moved to dedicated.

Well, scripts has been rewritten as well, and right now working good.